# 500 Internal Server Error and undefined variable error in codeigniter in foreach loop?

Tags: mysql, foreach, codeigniter-3

I searched a lot in google but didn't find any solution for my problem.its a last hope to get solution. I remove index.php from url with htaccess.
My htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

my problem is in my entire codeigniter project in any view if i think to fetch data from database it gives me error of undefined variable. In chrome debugger it shows `500 Internal Server Error`.
Variable that i am using for fetching data shows this variable is undefined and also shows 505 internal error.I am sharing my mvc code.please review my code i am using version 3.

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pay_slips extends CI_Model{

function __construct()  
      {       
        parent::__construct();  
      } 


      function select() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM india_salary_slip_details');
         return $query;
        } 

}
```

Controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pay_slips extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->load->model('pay_slips');
    }



    public function index()  
      {  
         //load the database  
         $this->load->database();  
         //load the model  
         $this->load->model('select');  
         //load the method of model  
         $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
         //return the data in view  
         $this->load->view('responsibilities/pay_slips', $data);  
      }   


}
```

View:

```
   <?php  
     foreach ($h->result() as $row)
       {  
        ?><tr>  
           <td><?php echo $row->PAY_MONTH;?></td>  
           <td><?php echo $row->PAY_YEAR;?></td>  
          </tr>  
      <?php }  ?>
```

image with errors:
[image]

I have data in database.Eveything is fine but still dont know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller replace $query with this:

```
    $query=$this->db->select('*')->from('india_salary_slip_details')->get();
```

load data base in your model.
then try to var_dump($data) in controller.You will find out what is wrong.

Comment: replace $data['h']=$this->slips->get_salary();  by  $data['h']=$this->pay_slips->get_salary();

Comment: for further reference [link]https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: turn error reporting on then you will get error message

Answer (score 0):

```
MODEL
=====
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pay_slips extends CI_Model{

function __construct()  
      {       
        parent::__construct();  
      } 


      function get_salary() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM india_salary_slip_details');
         return $query->result_array();
        } 

}

CONTROLLER
==========
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pay_slips extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->load->model('pay_slips','slips');
    }

    public function index()  
      {  
         //load the database  
         $this->load->database();  
         //load the model  
         //$this->load->model('select');  
         //load the method of model  
         $data['h']=$this->slips->select();  
         //return the data in view  
         $this->load->view('responsibilities/pay_slips', $data);  
      }   
}

VIEW
====
<?php  
     foreach ($h as $row)
     {  
        ?><tr>  
           <td><?php echo $row['PAY_MONTH'];?></td>  
           <td><?php echo $row['PAY_YEAR'];?></td>  
          </tr>  
<?php }  ?>
```